# Loop execute statement in Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, insert, execute

I have the following sccenario:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`test`@`%` PROCEDURE `prTest`()
BEGIN
     SET @prepared_sql = 'select field1, field2 from table_data1');

     PREPARE stmt FROM @prepared_sql;
     EXECUTE stmt;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

I have to open the "stmt" in a loop. How do I read this loop and each row, getting the values of "field1" and "field2" ​​and insert the values ​​in another table?

Answer (score -1):

Resolved:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`test`@`%` PROCEDURE `prTest`()
BEGIN
     SET @prepared_sql = 'insert into table_data2
                          select field1, field2 from table_data1');

     PREPARE stmt FROM @prepared_sql;
     EXECUTE stmt;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Comment: A piece of text to accompany such a code snipped is usually in order.